# Dynamic ComboBox in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a DataGridView with 4 columns, one of them being a drop-down (ComboBox) column.  The values in this column must be distinct so once a given drop-down values is selected in a row, I'd like it to not be available in any of the drop-downs in other rows.  If a given value is unselected it should show up in the drop-downs again.  I found a few articles with similar examples ([1](http://codeedifice.blogspot.com/2007/12/dynamic-combobox-in-datagridview.html),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551768/databinding-of-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089889/how-do-i-set-up-a-datagridview-comboboxcolumn-with-a-different-datasource-in-each)); however, all of them seem to involve subscribing to an event and manually populating the ComboBox.

- Is there a way to accomplish this with databinding alone (maybe to an IEnumerable that's basically a `all.Except(selected)` Linq query)?
- If databinding alone isn't enough, is there a better way to do it than the examples I found?

*I'm a bit new to WinForms development so having trouble telling apart good advice from "yeah...that'll work, sort of".*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your searching so far is correct - there is no better way to provide different lists to comboboxes in the same DataGridView column than subscribing to events (usually `CellBeginEdit` and `CellEndEdit` and then setting the DataSource for an individual `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`).

By way of evidence of this, I'll point you to the excellent [DataGridView FAQ](http://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%2520To%2520Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%2520FAQ.doc&ei=anuLTtL4GMjHtAbVotyTAg&usg=AFQjCNFxVe3EWtsJNP7xXxENGfV6dxU0EQ) which was written by Mark Rideout, the DataGridView program manager at Microsoft. The FAQ has a full solution to your problem which is very similar to the links you post.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know if things had gotten better with WPF controls?

Comment: @R0MANARMY I've not specifically tried this sort of chained combo box source with any of the WPF grids, but in general I've found WPF much nicer to work with - even when doing slightly unusual things - than winforms. Pretty sure you could use the advanced WPF binding to bind specific controls to some function to support this.