# Getting selected value of dynamic textboxes and comboboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform in c# that I dynamically created two comboboxes and a textbox.  When a user selects  say the month and year and enters a value in the text box I want get the related comboboxes values when the button is clicked to save.  By default the month and year combobox will have the current month and year selected.

There is also another part in the same screen where data will be populated for the previous month like Jan to March for the current year in the comboboxes and the text boxes if available.

I am not sure whether this approach is correct or I should go with a datagridview.  Below is the screenshot and my code.  Any suggestions on how I can do this.

**Screenshot**
[image]

**Code**

```
private void createComboMonths()
{
   int width = 79;
   int height = 24;
   int spacing = 28;
   ComboBox[] SubMonths = new ComboBox[12];
   for (int i = 0; i <= 11; ++i)
   {
       SubMonths[i] = new ComboBox();
       SubMonths[i].Name = "SubMonths";
       SubMonths[i].DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
       SubMonths[i].Size = new Size(width, height);
       SubMonths[i].Location = new Point(56, (i * height) + spacing);
       SubMonths[i].Items.Add("January");
       SubMonths[i].Items.Add("February");
       SubMonths[i].Items.Add("March");
       SubMonths[i].Items.Add("April");
       SubMonths[i].Items.Add("May");
       SubMonths[i].Items.Add("June");
       SubMonths[i].Items.Add("July");
       SubMonths[i].Items.Add("August");
       SubMonths[i].Items.Add("September");
       SubMonths[i].Items.Add("October");
       SubMonths[i].Items.Add("November");
       SubMonths[i].Items.Add("December");
       SubMonths[i].SelectedItem = DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM");
       plSubscription.Controls.Add(SubMonths[i]);

    }
}


private void createComboYears()
{
   int width = 79;
   int height = 24;
   int spacing = 28;
   ComboBox[] SubYears = new ComboBox[12];
   for (int i = 0; i <= 11; ++i)
   {
       SubYears[i] = new ComboBox();
       SubYears[i].Name = "SubYears";
       SubYears[i].DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
       SubYears[i].Size = new Size(width, height);
       SubYears[i].Location = new Point(145, (i * height) + spacing);
       plSubscription.Controls.Add(SubYears[i]);
       fillComboData(SubYears[i]); // Function to fill the last 5 years
    }
}



private void createTextBoxes()
{
   int width = 79;
   int height = 24;
   int spacing = 28;
   TextBox[] subAmt = new TextBox[12];
   for (int i = 0; i <= 11; ++i)
   {
      subAmt[i] = new TextBox();
      subAmt[i].Name = "SubAmt" + i;
      subAmt[i].Border.Class = "TextBoxBorder";
      subAmt[i].Size = new Size(width, height);
      subAmt[i].Margin = new Padding(10, 10, 10, 10);
      subAmt[i].Location = new Point(279, (i * height) + spacing);
      subAmt[i].KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txtJanAmt_KeyPress);
      plSubscription.Controls.Add(subAmt[i]);

    }
 }


private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtSubs = new DataTable();
    dtSubs.Columns.Add("SubscriberID", typeof(string));
    dtSubs.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(string));
    dtSubs.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(string));
    dtSubs.Columns.Add("SubAmt", typeof(string));
    DataRow row = dtSubs.NewRow(); 
    foreach (Control c in plSubscription.Controls)
    {
        //<- Not sure how do I get the selected row as in the screenshot
    }
}
```

EDIT 1

I used the below code that gets the data from the datatable but not able to do the following

1. How do I set the value of the comboboxes as selected when I get it from the datatable
2. For the textbox how do I get the value from the datatable
3. Whenever there is data available I want that row to be readonly.

Thanks in advance

**Changed code**

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   #region Grid Column Names
   DataGridViewComboBoxColumn mntCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
   mntCmb.HeaderText = "Month";
   mntCmb.Name = "Month";
   mntCmb.DataSource = dt;
   mntCmb.DisplayMember = "paidformonth";
   mntCmb.ValueMember = "paidformonth";
   // <-How do I set the column as selected.

   DataGridViewComboBoxColumn yearCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
   yearCmb.HeaderText = "Year";
   yearCmb.Name = "Year";
   yearCmb.DisplayMember = "paidforyear";
   yearCmb.ValueMember = "paidforyear";
   // <-How do I set the column as selected.

   DataGridViewTextBoxColumn amount = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
   amount.HeaderText = "Subscription Amount";
   amount.Name = "Subscription Amount";
   amount.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
   // <-How do I set this column with the value from the datatable

   #endregion

   dgvSubscriptions.Columns.AddRange(mntCmb, yearCmb, amount);
}
```

**Edit 2**

I seem to be confused as to why I am getting 3 rows with 6 columns.  The datatable only has 2 rows and 3 columns.  I am using the above code.  I added the ID column just to see what happens.  See the screenshot below.  I have

```
dgvSubscriptions.AllowUserToAddRows = true
```

as I want the user to add rows and enter more data to save.  What I am trying to do here is to get a subscription list of months/years that were paid and allow users to add subscription for say May, June assuming Jan to April was paid.

[image]

**Edit 3**

I even set the DataPropertyName instead of the ValueMember still no changes

**Edited Code**

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn yearCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
yearCmb.HeaderText = "Year";
yearCmb.Name = "Year";
//yearCmb.DataSource = dt;
yearCmb.DisplayMember = "paidforyear";
//yearCmb.ValueMember = "paidforyear";
yearCmb.DataPropertyName= "paidforyear";
yearCmb.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
yearCmb.ReadOnly = true;
dgvSubscriptions.Columns.Add(yearCmb);
```

**Edit 4**

Below is the actual code that is causing the duplicate columns

```
dgvSubscriptions.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgvSubscriptions.ColumnCount = 1;
dgvSubscriptions.Columns[0].Name = "ID";
dgvSubscriptions.Rows.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i <dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     dgvSubscriptions.Rows.Add();
     #region Grid Column Names
     DataGridViewComboBoxColumn mntCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
     mntCmb.HeaderText = "Month";
     mntCmb.Name = "Month";
     //mntCmb.DataSource = dt;
     mntCmb.DisplayMember = "paidformonth";
     mntCmb.DataPropertyName = "paidformonth";
     //mntCmb.ValueMember = "paidformonth";
     mntCmb.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
     mntCmb.ReadOnly = true;
     dgvSubscriptions.Columns.Add(mntCmb);


     DataGridViewComboBoxColumn yearCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
     yearCmb.HeaderText = "Year";
     yearCmb.Name = "Year";
     //yearCmb.DataSource = dt;
     yearCmb.DisplayMember = "paidforyear";
     //yearCmb.ValueMember = "paidforyear";
     yearCmb.DataPropertyName= "paidforyear";
     yearCmb.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
     yearCmb.ReadOnly = true;
     dgvSubscriptions.Columns.Add(yearCmb);

     DataGridViewTextBoxColumn amount = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
     amount.HeaderText = "Subscription Amount";
     amount.Name = "Subscription Amount";
     amount.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
     //amount.DataPropertyName = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
     amount.DataPropertyName="subamount";
     amount.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
     amount.ReadOnly = true;
     dgvSubscriptions.Columns.Add(amount);

     #endregion

}
```

**Edit 5**

I used IRSOG code with some modification and below is the full working code.

**Working Code**

```
public struct Data
{
    public List<string> Mon { get; set; }
    public List<string> Year { get; set; }
}

private void fillGridData(DataTable dt)
{
  List<string> Mon = new List<string>() { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

  List<string> Year = new List<string>();
  int CurrentYear = DateTime.UtcNow.Year;
  int NextYear = CurrentYear + 1;
  int LastFiveYears = CurrentYear - 5;
  for (int i = LastFiveYears; i <= NextYear; i++)
  {
     Year.Add(i.ToString());
  }
  List<Data> _Data = new List<Data>();
  for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
  {
     _Data.Add(new Data() { Mon = Mon, Year = Year });
  }

   dgvSubscriptions.Rows.Clear();
   dgvSubscriptions.Refresh();
   dgvSubscriptions.Visible = true;
   dgvSubscriptions.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Trebuchet MS", 8F, FontStyle.Regular);
   dgvSubscriptions.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
   dgvSubscriptions.AutoResizeColumns();
   dgvSubscriptions.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;
   dgvSubscriptions.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
   dgvSubscriptions.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
   dgvSubscriptions.Dock = DockStyle.None;
   dgvSubscriptions.BackgroundColor = this.BackColor;
   dgvSubscriptions.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
   dgvSubscriptions.AllowUserToAddRows = true;


  // If dt.Rows.Count > 0 then show the data - do not allow to change existing data
  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
  {

    dgvSubscriptions.Rows.Clear();
    dgvSubscriptions.Refresh();

    #region Grid Column Names
    dgvSubscriptions.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgvSubscriptions.Rows.Clear();
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn mntCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    mntCmb.HeaderText = "Month";
    mntCmb.Name = "Month";
    mntCmb.DataSource = Mon;
    mntCmb.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "";
    dgvSubscriptions.Columns.Add(mntCmb);

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn yearCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    yearCmb.HeaderText = "Year";
    yearCmb.Name = "Year";
    yearCmb.DataSource = Year;
    yearCmb.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "";
    dgvSubscriptions.Columns.Add(yearCmb);

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn amount = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    amount.HeaderText = "Subscription Amount";
    amount.Name = "Subscription Amount";
    amount.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    amount.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "";
    dgvSubscriptions.Columns.Add(amount);
    #endregion

    #region Populate Grid
    for (int i = 0; i <dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
       dgvSubscriptions.Rows.Add();

       dgvSubscriptions.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();  // Month
       dgvSubscriptions.Rows[i].Cells[0].ReadOnly = true; // do not allow the user to make changes
       dgvSubscriptions.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString(); // Year
       dgvSubscriptions.Rows[i].Cells[1].ReadOnly = true; // do not allow the user to make changes
       dgvSubscriptions.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();  // Subscription amount
       dgvSubscriptions.Rows[i].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true; // do not allow the user to make changes

    }
    #endregion

  }
  else // We come here if dt.Rows.Count is 0 we allow the user to select and save 
  {

    #region Grid Column Names
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn mntCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    mntCmb.HeaderText = "Month";
    mntCmb.Name = "Month";
    mntCmb.DataSource = Mon;

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn yearCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    yearCmb.HeaderText = "Year";
    yearCmb.Name = "Year";
    yearCmb.DataSource = Year;

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn amount = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    amount.HeaderText = "Subscription Amount";
    amount.Name = "Subscription Amount";
    amount.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    #endregion
    dgvSubscriptions.Columns.AddRange(mntCmb, yearCmb, amount);

    dgvSubscriptions.DataSource = _Data;
  }
  dgvSubscriptions.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Trebuchet MS", 8F, FontStyle.Regular);

}
```

Comment: You can simply cast the control c as TextBox, and check if it is not null, then get the text from textbox

Comment: Have you considered using a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) Instead?

Comment: @RajeevKumar I was able to do that but again if you see my screenshot I want the value comboboxes for the value entered in the textboxes

Comment: @JensKloster I think that would be the only way for my requirement.  Was hoping to see if there is some solution other that using a datagridview :)

Comment: Instead of using this,use DataGridView and set unic id for each row,then you can easlly get each row data.

Comment: @IRSOG not sure what you mean can you show me some sample code of what you mean

Comment: @Adrian: i don't have vs.net now,but you can create this structure in a datagridview,and get each selected row data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using this,use `DataGridView`
Try this:

With Calling `GetCurrentRowValues` method you can get selected row information's.

**Complete Code**

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> Mon = new List<string>() { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", " June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
            List<string> Year = new List<string>() { "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006" };
            List<Data> _Data = new List<Data>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                _Data.Add(new Data() { Mon = Mon, Year = Year });
            }
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn moonCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            moonCmb.HeaderText = "Month";
            moonCmb.Name = "Month";
            moonCmb.DataSource = Mon;

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn yearCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            yearCmb.HeaderText = "Year";
            yearCmb.Name = "Year";
            yearCmb.DataSource = Year;
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn amount = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            amount.HeaderText = "Amount";
            amount.Name = "Amount";
            dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(moonCmb, yearCmb, amount);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = _Data;

        }

        private void GetCurrentRowValues()
        {
            var mon = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Month"].Value;
            var year = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Year"].Value;
            var amont = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Amount"].Value;
        }

    }
    public struct Data
    {
        public List<string> Mon { get; set; }
        public List<string> Year { get; set; }
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

**New edit-From data table**

```
        #region Grid Column Names
        dgvSubscriptions.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvSubscriptions.ColumnCount = 1;
        dgvSubscriptions.Columns[0].Name = "ID";
        dgvSubscriptions.Rows.Clear();

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn mntCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        mntCmb.HeaderText = "Month";
        mntCmb.Name = "Month";
        //mntCmb.DataSource = dt;
        mntCmb.DisplayMember = "paidformonth";
        mntCmb.DataPropertyName = "paidformonth";
        //mntCmb.ValueMember = "paidformonth";
        mntCmb.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "";
        mntCmb.ReadOnly = true;
        mntCmb.Items.Add("april");
        mntCmb.Items.Add("jun");
        mntCmb.Items.Add("jull");
        dgvSubscriptions.Columns.Add(mntCmb);

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn yearCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        yearCmb.HeaderText = "Year";
        yearCmb.Name = "Year";
        //yearCmb.DataSource = dt;
        yearCmb.DisplayMember = "paidforyear";
        //yearCmb.ValueMember = "paidforyear";
        yearCmb.DataPropertyName = "paidforyear";
        yearCmb.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "";
        yearCmb.Items.Add("2001");
        yearCmb.Items.Add("2002");
        yearCmb.Items.Add("2003");
        yearCmb.ReadOnly = true;
        dgvSubscriptions.Columns.Add(yearCmb);
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn amount = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        amount.HeaderText = "Subscription Amount";
        amount.Name = "Subscription Amount";
        amount.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        //amount.DataPropertyName = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
        amount.DataPropertyName = "subamount";
        amount.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "";
        amount.ReadOnly = true;
        dgvSubscriptions.Columns.Add(amount);
        #endregion
```

**Fill it**

```
       for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dgvSubscriptions.Rows.Add();
            dgvSubscriptions.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            dgvSubscriptions.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            dgvSubscriptions.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
            dgvSubscriptions.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Hmm... I started like this way and got lost halfway:).  Let me try with your code and see.  Just one question - The list string Year can I want to have the last 5 years plus the current and next year

Comment: Your codes works just need to find out how to restrict the user from entering numbers and decimal points in the Amount column

Comment: @Adrian:first question is not hard to implement,and sec question:You must create custom dataGridView column where place any control you want:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx

Comment: I used your code and it works, this is ok if there is no data in the datatable.  But when there is data in the datatable I assign the datasource as the data table.  I edited my question with some new questions.  Hope you can guide me some more :)

Comment: @Adrian:insert struct of your datatable

Comment: can you check my edit 2 section not sure what I am doing wrong there

Comment: I have updated the actual code check Edit 4. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Adrian:i need your data table,i what your project,if you can upload and send me link of your project.

Comment: The datatable consists of 3 columns that I get from a database. paidformonth - varchar(20), paidforyear int, subamt decimal(8,2).  This is the structure of the database table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28362/discussion-between-adrian-and-irsog)

Comment: @Adrian:i write a complete example see it

Comment: seems to show an error while loading the grid System.Argument.Exception: DataGridComboBoxcell value not valid.  To replace the default dialog please handle the DataError Event.  Thanks once again

Comment: @Adrian:this is because you donot init your comboboxes with years and month,come to chat to explain

Answer (score 1):

The forms `ActiveControl` property can help you.

```
var focusedCtrl = this.ActiveControl;
var siblings = Controls.Where(c => c.Location.Y == focusedCtrl.Location.Y).ToList();
foreach (Control c in siblings)
{
   // all thise controls are on the same row, providede that the allign
}
```

Still I would sugget the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx). It seems to be a better choise for a structure that looks like yours.

Comment: Thanks let me see if I can get it work with the datagridview.  My issue that I had when I tried with the DataGridView was how to populate the combobox column dynamically.  I will try and see

Comment: @Adrian I [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648648/dynamic-combobox-in-a-datagridview) your problem. Perhaps you need a better GridView. I Always use [XtraGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/) but it is not free.

Answer (score 1):

I’d go with the DataGridView but if you still want to keep this structure you might want to update KeyPressed event handler to look something like this

```
private string lastUsedTextBox = string.Empty;
private string lastEnteredValue = string.Empty;

private void txtJanAmt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
lastUsedTextBox = (sender as TextBox).Name;                      
lastEnteredValue = (sender as TextBox).Text;                       
}
```

And then when you press the save button you have everything stored here.

If you need to save all the data you can use dictionary or something like that.

Comment: Thanks I did go with the datagridview but still some issue check my edited question.  Not sure how to set the values from the DataTable of the comboboxes